# FFT using recursive python function

Tags: python, fft, rosetta-code

I am trying to use the following [code for finding FFT](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform#Python:_Recursive) of a given list.

After a lot of trials I have found that this code runs only for an input list having `2^m` or `2^m+1` elements.

Can you please clarify why this is so and whether it can be modified to use an input list containing some other number of elements.
(P.S. I have an input list of 16001 elements)

```
    from cmath import exp, pi

    def fft(x):
        N = len(x)
        if N <= 1: return x
        even = fft(x[0::2])
        odd =  fft(x[1::2])
        T= [exp(-2j*pi*k/N)*odd[k] for k in xrange(N/2)]
        return [even[k] + T[k] for k in xrange(N/2)] + \
        [even[k] - T[k] for k in xrange(N/2)]

    print( ' '.join("%5.3f" % abs(f) 
            for f in fft([1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0])) )
```

Edit 1
Could You please tell the difference between the previous and the following function definition:

```
def fft(x):
    N = len(x)
    T = exp(-2*pi*1j/N)
    if N > 1:
        x = fft(x[::2]) + fft(x[1::2])
        for k in xrange(N/2):
            xk = x[k]
            x[k] = xk + T**k*x[k+N/2]
            x[k+N/2] = xk - T**k*x[k+N/2]
    return x
```

Edit 2: In fact this code(under Edit 1) does work, (sorry for the fault in indentation and variable naming earlier) which is why I want to understand the difference between the two.(this works for 16001 elements too!)

Comment: Your code under _Edit 1_ does not run because the indentation is wrong. Also, there is no `return` for the case `N < 1`. The original algorithm is correct but only for an input list with a power-of-two elements. Use the NumPy version as shown in my answer for your 16001 elements. It works and is faster than anything you can write in pure Python.

Comment: Added another answer to your edited version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer to the Edited Version

While this  version:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    range = xrange

from cmath import exp, pi

def fft2(x):
    N = len(x)
    T = exp(-2*pi*1j/N)
    if N > 1:
        x = fft2(x[::2]) + fft2(x[1::2])
        for k in range(N//2):
            xk = x[k]
            x[k] = xk + T**k*x[k+N//2]
            x[k+N//2] = xk - T**k*x[k+N//2]
    return x
```

seems to work for a power-of-two number of inputs:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.fft import fft as np_fft

data = [1, 2, 3, 4]
np.allclose(fft2(data), np_fft(data))
```

is `True`.

It does not give correct results for a different number of inputs.

```
data2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
np.allclose(fft2(data2), np_fft(data2))
```

is `False`.

It is still based on the assumption that the number of inputs is a power of two, even though it does not throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Looks like there's no way to avoid numpy. Or, can something be done to make a single script file which does no require importing numpy?

Comment: NumPy is your friend. :) Don't avoid it, use it. Have a look at [PyInstaller](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki), if you want a standalone program. BTW, if the answer solved your problem you can [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) it.

Comment: Thanks, I am using Numpy now

Answer (score 0):

### Algorithm

This algorithm works only for a power of two number of input data.
Have a look at the [theory](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sys.html?highlight=recursionlimit#sys.getrecursionlimit).

This is a improved version that checks for this pre-condition:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

if sys.version_info.major < 3:
    range = xrange

from cmath import exp, pi

def fft(x):
    N = len(x)
    if N <= 1: 
        return x
    if N % 2 > 0:
        raise ValueError("size of x must be a power of 2")
    even = fft(x[::2])
    odd =  fft(x[1::2])
    r = range(N//2)
    T = [exp(-2j * pi * k / N) * odd[k] for k in r]
    [even[k] for k in r]
    res = ([even[k] + T[k] for k in r] +
           [even[k] - T[k] for k in r])
    return res

input_data = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
print(' '.join("%5.3f" % abs(f) for f in fft(input_data)))
```

NumPy comes with its optimized version of a FFT function.
It works for sizes different than the power of two.
But it will be much slower because it needs to apply a different algorithm.

For example:

```
from numpy.fft import fft as np_fft
​
n = 1000
a = np.arange(n ** 2)
b = np.arange(n ** 2 - 10)
```

The runtime for the power-of-two case:

```
%timeit np_fft(a)
10 loops, best of 3: 59.3 ms per loop
```

is much less than that where this not the case:

```
%timeit np_fft(b)
1 loops, best of 3: 511 ms per loop
```

### Recursion Limit

Python has built-in recursion limit of 1000:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getrecursionlimit()
1000
```

But you can increase the recursion limit:

```
sys.setrecursion(50000)
```

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/sys.html?highlight=recursionlimit#sys.getrecursionlimit) tell you why:

```
getrecursionlimit()
```

> Return the current value of the recursion limit, the maximum depth of the Python interpreter stack. This limit prevents infinite recursion from causing an overflow of the C stack and crashing Python. It can be set by setrecursionlimit().

```
setrecursionlimit()
```

> Set the maximum depth of the Python interpreter stack to limit. This limit prevents infinite recursion from causing an overflow of the C stack and crashing Python.
>
> The highest possible limit is platform-dependent. A user may need to set the limit higher when they have a program that requires deep recursion and a platform that supports a higher limit. This should be done with care, because a too-high limit can lead to a crash.

Comment: Sorry, but increasing the recursion limit did not help in using this 'fft(x)' for my 16001 element input list

Answer (score 0):

in the above code in this line:

```
T = [exp(-2j * pi * k / N) * odd[k] for k in r]
```

if you observe closely at this part:
`exp(-2j * pi * k / N)` would lead all your output vectors in clockwise direction, for the right anticlockwise answer replace `exp(-2j * pi * k / N)` with `exp(2j * pi * k / N)`
 as `omega = exp(2j * pi * k / N)`